# Why button in storyboard is not located in appropriate location in ios8?

Tags: ios, iphone, button, ios8

Here is design of my storyboard:

[image]

And here is output:

[image]

Why this button is not located in its correct location?

Comment: @Fogmeister I can't find  the square on it in the bottom right of the editor..

Comment: @Fogmeister Do you mean in Attribute inspector?

Comment: Posted an answer with a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common question on Stack Overflow. You need to add auto layout constraints to the button. It doesn't know if you mean "in the centre" or "300 points from the left". You can add them by selecting the button and tapping the button with the square on it in the bottom right of the editor.

These are the buttons.

[image]

The buttons are...

1. Align views. Either multiple views or along a single view with its superview.
2. Add constraints to a specific view. Left, Top, Height, Width, etc...
3. Auto constraints. Update frames to constraints. Etc...
4. Resizing options.

You need to add constraints to **ALL** of the views in your app.

So, on `button2` you will need to tell it...

> 1. How far down from the top.
> 2. Align the button to the centre of the superview.

For `button1` you will need...

> 1. How for down from the top.
> 2. How far in from the left.

For the map...

> 1. Zero from the bottom, left, and right. (That's three separate constraints)
> 2. How much spacing between `button1` and the top of the map.